# Ruby on Rails, javascripts conflicts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using this [example for file uploader](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) and [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) application in ruby.
In order to get charts work, I had to add following files to my app/assets/javascript:

highcharts.js
jquery-1.4.2.min.js
rais.js

And to my charts.html.erb following code:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min", "rails", "highcharts" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

My charts look beautiful but I cannot upload the files. There is some kind of a conflict between those javascripts and etc.
I want to move those 3 files to another directory and define a path for the code in charts.html.erb to that it will find where all neccessary files are.

I do not know where to write a defined path in the code.
something like this:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "public/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min", "public/javascripts/rails", "public/javascripts/highcharts" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

but it tells me an error in a console:

```
Started GET "/assets/public/javascripts/rails.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-15 16:21:19 +0100
Served asset /public/javascripts/rails.js - 404 Not Found (33ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/public/javascripts/rails.js")
```

:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using the includes in the application.js file instead of adding them like that?

Comment: I did not and I have to idea how to do it. I am pretty new to rails-)

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2 is pretty old; version 1.9 was very recently released.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @Pointy, but highcharts provide exactly this version and I have no idea if it works with 1.9 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define each and every javascript file name explicitly in latest rails versions.

This is because of `application.js` file which requires every js for you in tree form.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

You just need to do like that -

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: This is how should be used the [asset-pipeline in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) .

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Good answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question: you can define your own path for assets (but it's not recommended), just add slash before the path. Like
 `<%= javascript_include_tag "/public/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js", "/public/javascripts/rails.js", "/public/javascripts/highcharts.js" %>`